# Project Euler number 3 - Python

Tags: python

I was curious if anyone could fix my code, this is for project Euler Question 3 (What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143 ?), as of now, I am sticking to a program that will find all the prime factors in 100, but am getting an error message for divide by 0, in my head the code seems to work, but it isn't. Unless absolutely necessary, I'd like to keep the while loops. Thanks.

```
def isPrime(A):
    x = 2
    while x < A:
            if A % x == 0:
                    return False
            x += 1
    return A

def isInt(x):
    if x == int(x):
            return True
    return False

A = int(input("Number? "))
counter = 2

while counter <= A:
    if isInt(A/isPrime(counter)) == True: 
            print(counter)
    counter += 1

print ("Done")
```

Comment: I think you've got a bit confused with your types: if `isPrime()` runs the line `return False`, you are running the code `if isInt(A/False)`, which makes no sense (and `False` is probably coerced to 0, making it `if isInt(A/0)`)

Comment: Well ... `isPrime` can return `false`. Want to guess what numerical value is associated with it?

Comment: bad way to find if a quotient is an integer! just test for `A % B == 0`

Comment: BTW I solved it like this a long time ago (well, my code worked :)) I won't post it, but result is around 6800 :)

Comment: oh and your isprime function will take forever. Limit yourself to sqrt(A)+1 or it'll take a million years to complete.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the **full text** of any errors or tracebacks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the key issue is that `isPrime()` sometimes returns a boolean, and other times returns the input (an integer). You should avoid having functions that do too many things at once - a function called `isPrime()` should *just* indicate whether the input is prime or not (i.e. always return a boolean). Some other suggestions inline:

```
def isPrime(n): # n is a common variable name to use for "some number"
  x = 2
  while x < n:
    if n % x == 0:
      return False
    x += 1 # this isn't an ideal way to detect primes, can you think of any improvements?
  return True

def isInt(n): # use consistent variables - you used A above and x here, which is confusing
  return n == int(n) # you can just return the boolean result directly

input = int(input("Number? ")) # use meaningful variable names when possible
counter = 2

while counter <= input:
  # I *think* this is what you were trying to do:
  #   if counter is prime and input/counter is an integer.
  #   If not you may need to play with this conditional a bit
  # also no need to say ' == True' here
  if isPrime(counter) and isInt(input/counter): 
    print(counter)
  counter += 1

print ("Done")
```

This should run (whether it works or not, I leave to you!), but it's still not as efficient as it could be. As you get into harder Project Euler problems you'll need to start paying careful attention to efficiency and optimizations. I'll let you dig into this further, but here's two hints to get you started:

- Incrementing by one every time is wasteful - if you know something is not divisible by 2 you also know it's not divisible by 4, 8, 16, and so on, yet your code will do those checks.
- In general finding primes is expensive, and it's a very repetitive operation - can you re-use any work done to find one prime when finding the next one?